# MobilePush Android SDK(8.0.8) causing higher application wakeups and device battery consumption

Tags: fuel-sdk, mobilesdk, mobilepush-android

We upgraded to SFMCSdk Android (8.0.8) from the previous version and since it was released, we have received alerts on Google Console of excessive wakeups on our application, which implies excessive device’s battery consumption. And we are now receiving complaints from our clients.

As far as we go through the investigation, we've seen this occur since we upgraded to version 8.0.8. Mostly affecting to Android OS 13 (Api 33). We have identified that wakeups are being caused by *com.mydomain.mysubdomain.com.salesforce.marketingcloud.WAKE_FOR_ALARM*, wich is declare in the Salesforce Library com.salesforce.marketingcloud.MCReceiver

```
        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" />

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />

            <action
                android:name="**com.mydomain.mysubdomain.com.salesforce.marketingcloud.WAKE_FOR_ALARM**" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I am wondering if anybody else is experiencing this issue and if you have found any workarounds.

Thanks

Comment: Open a support case.

Comment: You should enable logging and review the output for any errors or obvious issues. There are a finite number of reasons the SDK will wake when your SDK is in the background, and most of them have to do with some comms issue (or similar). Also, open a support ticket ;)

Comment: Hi @BillMote , we have already opened a support case 44354881, but it has been closed with no resolution. We attached the evidences we have. A part from that we are working on log enabling but this is not a crash that we can reproduce itself on a device and attach a screenshot as it was requested by the agent.

Comment: What crash? You say nothing about a crash in your question above.

Comment: What did your logs say? Review them. If something is going wrong it will be in there.

Comment: Thank you for the case #. I've reached out internally, but you're going to need to get logs from an affected Samsung S21 w/Android 13 -- although, this appears to be ~1.6% if I'm reading the screenshots correctly.

Comment: Support should have reached out to you for additional data.